# jQuery class selector performance (confused)

Tags: jquery, performance, jquery-selectors

So is `$('table.selectable td.capable input:text')` preferable to `$('table.selectable td input:text')`? In other words, does specifying a class speed up or slow down the selection (assuming it isn't absolutely required in this scenario)?

Comment: that's a good question.Wanted to ask a similar one.

Comment: Run your own benchmarks.

Comment: The key point is, they are not the same result set, if there are `<td>` without the `.capable` class, which still match.

Comment: @Orbling This is true. I guess I should have specified that this doesn't make a difference in the context of this question.

Comment: Aye, I assumed that, otherwise the question would be moot.  The point as I mention in my answer, is that you shouldn't have redundant information in your selector, it just adds to the workload with no benefit.  If it aids code clarity and has negligible performance detriment, then keep it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did not check the Sizzle implementation, but in the best case, `td` would map to something like [getElementsByTagName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName) and `.capable` to something like [getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName), if available. So both would be comparable in terms of speed.

However, there is no `getElementsByTagNameAndClassName()` method as far as I know, so resolving `td.capable` probably requires an additional filtering pass after the DOM call. So, I'm quite inclined to think it would be slower.

Naturally, a benchmark would tell for sure.

Comment: Good point. I'm about to do a benchmark, I'll let y'all know.

Answer (score 3):

So I did some benchmarking with firebug, and in the particular example I listed in the question, the latter (without the td class specifier) is faster.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the context.

Generally, the more sub-checks that need to be made, the slower it will be, as each takes time.  The point is, they are obviously not necessarily the same results.  One is a sub-set of the other.

For the most part, aim to have the minimal number of selectors required to target the specific set you require.  Also bare in mind that some selectors perform far better (due to browser method availability) than others.  ID selectors `#id` and in modern browsers tag selectors, are far quicker than class searches `.class`, which require iterative string analysis of the `.className` parameter, or indeed attribute based searching, which is much the same usually.

If in doubt, perform metrics.