# jQuery performance - select by data-attr or by class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Which is faster and why? Selecting div (for plugin needs) by `$('div[data-something]')` or `$('div.something')`? I lean towards the former since it's "cleaner".

Based on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179540/jquery-class-selector-performance-confused) I know I shouldn't be using both. However I didn't find out whether there is a difference between these.

Comment: good questions... can someone try $('*').each for me ? :) always wanted to know what it does or what its performence is

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It will vary by browser. Nearly all browsers now support `querySelectorAll`, and jQuery will use it when it can. `querySelectorAll` can be used with attribute presence selectors, so if it's there jQuery doesn't have to do the work, it can offload it to the engine.

For older browsers without `querySelectorAll`, jQuery will obviously have to do more work, but even IE8 has it.

As with most of these things, your best bet is:

1. Don't worry about it until/unless you see a problem, and
2. If you see a problem, profile it on the browsers you intend to support and then make an informed decision.

Answer (score 17):

In Chrome 16 at least, [there is no difference](http://jsperf.com/jq-data-vs-class). However, if you make the class selector less specific (`$(".test")` for example), it does outperform the other methods:

[image]

That was somewhat unexpected, because as ShankarSangoli mentions, I thought the `div.test` class selector would be faster.

Comment: Similar results on IE9, with `div.something` being very slightly faster than `div[data-something]`, but both being much slower than `.something`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Thanks for saving me a few minutes by running it in IE9 :) Firefox is much the same again. I've updated the screenshot to include those results.

Comment: `'.test'` will allow Sizzle to optimize the DOM selection by using `getElementsByClassName` instead of `querySelectorAll`. In most browsers, the former is currently quicker. But `'div.test'` will likely be faster in browsers like IE6 and IE7 that support neither `gEBCN` nor `qSA` because it narrows the manual class test to only `div` elements.

Comment: ...just ran your test in Opera, and as I expected, the results are reversed. I've seen time and again that their `qSA` is more optimized than some of their other DOM selection methods. **EDIT** Ah, I should have scrolled down. TJ has much of this info already!

Comment: @JamesAllardice: No worries. I thought IE8 might be interesting as well, so I ran that. Results are quite odd: `div.test` is fastest, and then `div[data-test]` and `.test` are tied.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Interesting. That appears to confirm amnotiam's reasoning a few comments up. Everyone - feel free to edit with an updated screenshot if you test in another browser!

Comment: @amnotiam - Thanks for updating the screenshot. I find it very interesting that Chrome 17 is significantly slower than Chrome 16!

Comment: @JamesAllardice: Well its probably just an indication that my computer is slower than yours. That's one of the problems with jsPerf. When there are multiple participants, you can only really compare different tests within a single browser.

Answer (score 3):

Selecting by class is always faster than attribute selector because jQuery tries to use the native `getElementByCalssName` first if supported by browsers. If not it uses the `querySelector` which uses css selectors to find the elements within the page.

Comment: No, jQuery will use `querySelectorAll` on nearly all browsers, rather than `getElementsByClassName`. It will fall back to `getElementsByClassName` for simple class selectors (not combined ones like `div.test`), but either way you're deferring to the browser's own CSS implementation on anything modern.

Comment: Seems a bit harsh to me, but probably it's because you said `div.something` would always be faster, and it isn't.

Comment: I didn't say `div.something` would be faster. I said selecting by class that attribute will be faster.

Comment: Given the OP's question, saying "selecting by class will be faster" means you're saying `div.something` is faster. If you mean something else (e.g., `.something`), you need to say that. Could be why (although again, seems harsh to me).